# jpackage has started failing on Mac OS due to: jlink failed with: WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.incubator.vector

Tags: java, maven, jlink, jpackage

jpackage has been working fine until today on Mac OS. Now it fails due to some internal use of an incubator package.

Is there a workaround for this? It still works fine on windows.

openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.44+15-CA (build 17.0.8+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.44+15-CA (build 17.0.8+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)

Mac OS 12.6.8 (21G725)

I am using jpackage from my maven build using exec plugin.

I am using jpackage with --input on an app image to create a non modular app. This has been fine before. Could this have become a problem?

Maven -X log

```
jdk.jpackage.internal.PackagerException: jlink failed with: WARNING: Using incubator modules: jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.incubator.vector
Error: jdk.tools.jlink.plugin.PluginException: Duplicate resources: {lib/libj2gss.dylib=[java.security.jgss, java.security.sasl], lib/jfr/default.jfc=[jdk.jshell, jdk.jsobject, jdk.jfr, jdk.jlink, jdk.jpackage, jdk.jstatd, jdk.localedata], conf/management/management.properties=[jdk.management.jfr, jdk.management.agent, jdk.sctp, jdk.xml.dom, jdk.unsupported, jdk.management, jdk.net, jdk.random, jdk.nio.mapmode, jdk.security.auth, jdk.unsupported.desktop, jdk.naming.rmi, jdk.zipfs, jdk.naming.dns, jdk.security.jgss], lib/jfr/profile.jfc=[jdk.jshell, jdk.jsobject, jdk.jfr, jdk.jlink, jdk.jpackage, jdk.jstatd, jdk.localedata], lib/libosxkrb5.dylib=[java.security.jgss, java.security.sasl], lib/libmanagement_ext.dylib=[jdk.management, jdk.naming.rmi, jdk.naming.dns], lib/libextnet.dylib=[jdk.net, jdk.random, jdk.nio.mapmode, jdk.sctp], conf/sound.properties=[java.desktop, java.instrument], conf/management/jmxremote.access=[jdk.management.jfr, jdk.management.agent, jdk.sctp, jdk.xml.dom, jdk.unsupported, jdk.management, jdk.net, jdk.random, jdk.nio.mapmode, jdk.security.auth, jdk.unsupported.desktop, jdk.naming.rmi, jdk.zipfs, jdk.naming.dns, jdk.security.jgss], lib/librmi.dylib=[java.rmi, java.scripting], lib/libsyslookup.dylib=[jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.javadoc, jdk.jdi, jdk.internal.ed, jdk.internal.le, jdk.jdeps, jdk.internal.opt, jdk.jartool, jdk.jconsole, jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.internal.jvmstat], lib/libattach.dylib=[jdk.charsets, jdk.attach], lib/libinstrument.dylib=[java.logging, java.instrument], lib/libjaas.dylib=[jdk.security.auth, jdk.unsupported.desktop, jdk.xml.dom, jdk.unsupported, jdk.zipfs, jdk.security.jgss], conf/logging.properties=[java.rmi, java.sql, jdk.incubator.vector, jdk.jdi, jdk.charsets, java.logging, java.transaction.xa, java.xml.crypto, java.xml, jdk.jfr, jdk.jstatd, jdk.httpserver, jdk.crypto.cryptoki, java.naming, jdk.internal.ed, java.prefs, java.net.http, jdk.compiler, java.security.sasl, jdk.internal.opt, jdk.jconsole, jdk.attach, jdk.crypto.ec, jdk.javadoc, jdk.jshell, jdk.editpad, jdk.internal.le, java.management, java.sql.rowset, jdk.jsobject, java.smartcardio, jdk.jlink, jdk.jdwp.agent, jdk.incubator.foreign, jdk.internal.jvmstat, java.security.jgss, java.scripting, jdk.dynalink, jdk.jdeps, jdk.accessibility, jdk.jartool, java.management.rmi, jdk.jpackage, jdk.localedata], lib/libj2pcsc.dylib=[java.sql, java.transaction.xa, java.xml.crypto, java.sql.rowset, java.xml, java.smartcardio, jdk.accessibility], lib/libj2pkcs11.dylib=[jdk.crypto.cryptoki, jdk.editpad, jdk.dynalink, jdk.crypto.ec], lib/libmanagement_agent.dylib=[jdk.management.jfr, jdk.management.agent], lib/libmanagement.dylib=[java.naming, java.management, java.net.http, java.management.rmi], conf/management/jmxremote.password.template=[jdk.management.jfr, jdk.management.agent, jdk.sctp, jdk.xml.dom, jdk.unsupported, jdk.management, jdk.net, jdk.random, jdk.nio.mapmode, jdk.security.auth, jdk.unsupported.desktop, jdk.naming.rmi, jdk.zipfs, jdk.naming.dns, jdk.security.jgss]}
```

Comment: My edit didn't work as you've removed the line separators. Could you please repost that, formatter as code

Comment: There were no line separators. I copy/pasted from the terminal.

Comment: The error seems to be from duplicate resources, not use of incubator modules: `Error: jdk.tools.jlink.plugin.PluginException: Duplicate resources`

Comment: I can't find it now, but there was a user with a similar question recently (I think they deleted their question). They were also using Zulu IIRC. In the end it turned out they had a broken JDK installation, and switching JDKs worked for them.

Comment: `<your command> 2>&1 | tee stacko.log` and paste that named text file formatted as code

Comment: To see if your JDK is the problem you can use the `jmod list` command on the relevant `jmods/*.jmod` files in the jdk installation directory, and then see if the reported duplicate resource indeed exists in both files.

Comment: Weirdly when I list (with show older versions) on azul there are 2 that look identical (same version info). Downloading the "older" release with same details (17.0.8+7 Azul Zulu: 17.44.15) as the "newer" release of same name seems to work. So yes it looks like azul have released a broken build. Or the website is buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I looks like azul released a broken jdk 17 build.

There were 2 listed with same version (when listing older versions is selected). The first didn't work, the second with same details does.

It is also possible that something went wrong when installing it, however the same thing happened on 2 different macs so think this is unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that finds this I got this when using jlink.

I got this as the error

Error: jdk.tools.jlink.plugin.PluginException: Duplicate resources: {lib/libj2gss.dylib=[java.security.jgss, java.security.sasl], conf/management/management.properties=[jdk.management, jdk.unsupported], bin/jrunscript=[java.sql, java.security.jgss, java.scripting, java.transaction.xa, java.xml, java.security.sasl], lib/libosxkrb5.dylib=[java.security.jgss, java.security.sasl], conf/sound.properties=[java.desktop, java.instrument], conf/management/jmxremote.access=[jdk.management, jdk.unsupported], lib/librmi.dylib=[java.rmi, java.scripting], bin/jstatd=[jdk.management, jdk.unsupported], lib/libinstrument.dylib=[java.logging, java.instrument], conf/logging.properties=[java.rmi, java.sql, java.logging, java.transaction.xa, java.management, java.xml, jdk.jfr, java.security.jgss, java.naming, java.scripting, java.prefs, java.net.http, java.security.sasl], lib/libj2pcsc.dylib=[java.sql, java.transaction.xa, java.xml], lib/libmanagement.dylib=[java.naming, java.management, java.net.http], conf/management/jmxremote.password.template=[jdk.management, jdk.unsupported]}

The broken jvm is zulu, from sdkman

```
 | 17.0.8       | zulu    | installed  | 17.0.8-zulu
```

fix

```
sdk install java 17.0.8-tem
```